# Can one use a milk frother on Pesach?

Tags: passover, technology, chametz-leaven

[Gourmia](https://www.gourmia.com/item.asp?item=10112) makes a milk frother. The machine consists of a stainless steel pitcher that has a rotating "wheel" with an optional removable wire wisk that attaches to the wheel. The whisk is used to create extra foam. The pitcher is placed on a base that acts as both the power source as well as the heater.

Assuming one observes the following throughout the year:

- Only milk is poured into the unit. (Milk is not marked as Kosher LePesach.)
- The unit is hand cleaned using soap and water and a clean paper towel. It does not touch the chametz sink.
- When pouring the milk, the unit does not touch a chametz cup and foam is spooned out using a clean plastic spoon.

Can this same unit be used during Hol Hamo'ed Pesach?

Comment: Doesn't the question boil down to wether the milk has chometz in it or not? Or am I missing something?

Comment: If the item is isolated from chametz during the year, why would you think you couldn't use it on Pesach?

Comment: Is the milk heated or frothed cold?

Comment: @sabbahillel It seems that you must have read some product item about this, as you could froth it cold. But, no, it is frothed and steamed. I should mention that the temperature never boils the milk, if that matters in the answer.

Comment: I have not read about this product, it was an obvious question to ask. I think that it is a matter that milk purchased before Pesach can be used on Pesach because it has become batel. **However** if purchased from a nonJew on Pesach, then the chametz in the milk was never batel and the milk cannot be used. You would need to CYLOR about the effect that this has on the pot.

Comment: This question should be closed per https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3760

Comment: @msh210 I defer to a moderator to decide this one. I don't care to haggle about M.Y. policy unless I feel very strongly about my side of the issue. As it is, between the answer and assorted comments on this question, it's not quite generating any *chiddushim*, IMO.

Comment: @msh210 I think this question could be generalized to whether it's permissible to use a year-round appliance that never touched chametz during Pesach

Comment: @Daniel That's not the attention of this question. I was specifically asking about milk or anything else related to this type of appliance. I got the answers, but, it seems to generate uncertainty, anyway. Re your suggestion, I think the answer is a rather obvious yes. According to a few rabbanim I have asked a hot water pot which only had water in it year round may be used during Pesach. Soda Stream seltzer makers can also, and that product has been addressed on MY somewhere. With the soda stream, it is recommended to use new bottles.

Comment: @DanF in that case I agree with msh210 that this question falls in the "complex scenario" bucket. I think the hallmark of such a question is one that has many variables and doesn't explain what angle the original poster wants answers to come from. Going on what's written in this question, it's not clear whether you're wondering about the kashrus of milk for Passover, the use of year-round appliances during Passover, whether soap and water have anything to do with Passover kashrus, or something else. To be asking about all of those things is too much for one question.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, let's simplify slightly: I have a pot that I used to cook regular milk (and nothing else) year-round; can I use that same pot for Pesach?

Okay let me simplify *that* question one more step: "on Purim, I took a brand-new pot. I poured in a gallon of water, tossed in one grain of wheat, and cooked it all for a few hours until the wheat had totally dissolved. then I washed it out really well. The pot sat, cold, clean, and empty, for a month. Now can I use that pot on Pesach? Or um, let's say it was one kernel of corn instead of wheat, and I'm Ashkenazic. Now can I use the pot?"

That's what this boils down to (pun intended). That year-round milk may contain trace amounts of *chametz*. (More likely vitamins that are *kitniyos*, but if it's on a line that's also producing malted milk, let's say trace amounts of chametz.) Before Pesach, such *chametz* is nullified 1:60 by volume. On Pesach, it's not.

You could buy such milk before Pesach, at which point it's nullified, and even keep it in the fridge and drink it on Pesach. You should not, however, go to the store on Pesach and buy milk that may contain, let's say, 0.1% chametz, because on Pesach, it's not *batel*.

When it's all said and done, standard practice is that if a pot was used for any amount of chametz -- or even kitniyos -- before Pesach, we kasher it before using it on Pesach. Which is probably your best solution here; clean it out well, wait 24 hours, then run the whole thing with boiling water.

Comment: Run it with boiling water? Probably easier to just froth some kosher lepesach milk. Kbolo kakh polto. We know how hot this got. Especially since this is an extreme Chumra anyway

Comment: I don't understand this answer. First you say that the chametz is batel before Pesach. Then you say that you should kasher the pot. How do you get from A to B? The pot was never used for chametz.

Comment: Per ^^^, I'm lost, myself. If it's nullified, it's not chametz. The rest of your shpiel doesn't seem relevant. What it comes to is really whether the year round milk is chametz or not, correct? According to what you've stated, it isn't b/c it's batel. As I stated, the pitcher hasn't touched anything chametz - while washing, it's held in one's hand. So, why would one have to kasher it at all?

Comment: @DanF our minhag  is not to rely on bitul when it comes to pots on Pesach. And yes, the point is that regular milk most likely contains trace amounts of chametz and/or kitniyos.

Comment: "our minhag is not to rely on bitul when it comes to pots on Pesach." Do you mean to say that if you buy milk before Pesach with no special Pesach hechsher, you can then drink that milk on Pesach but not cook with it?!